# ASP.NET HTML Helpers vs Generic HTML

Tags: asp.net

Are there any real benefits to using ASP.NET HTML Helpers over Generic HTML?
For me, I really do not see any "major" advantage. What do you think?

Update:

How flexible is it with Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: I don't want to post a link as an answer - but I'm reading http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2009/08/18/under-the-covers-of-html-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx and it seems to get into exactly what the helpers do besides rendering HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you want to do with posted data. If you'll just read form variables in controller action, then it doesn't really matter, but if you plan to use internal model binding, it may be much more tedious for you to write manual HTML.

Another plus with HTML helpers is when you want to create some more *complex* parts of your document like:

- Html.CheckBox()
- Html.ValidationMessage()
- etc.

Checkbox itself creates two inputs. A checkbox and a hidden field that makes it work with checked/unchecked state properly.

Comment: How flexible is it with Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: In the aspect of transversing through the elements. Get their id, classes, and also styling. Funny the way you call me "Colour" :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML Helpers are useful, when you want to reuse a piece of C# code and render some HTML dynamically without creating a full blown control.